# How to use css formatting in Full Calendar JSON string being passed from PHP page?

Tags: php, jquery, json, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3

I would like to format the title element of my calendar element, to take a new line and add the part I specify as bold. I have the following PHP page which is where I am passing the event data to the calendar which is all working ok.

```
 $deliveryDateArray[] = array(
            'mainID'  => $row["orderMainID"],
            'id'   => $row["orderBuildandDeliveryID"],
            'title'   => $row["lastName"] . " (" . $row["postcode"] . ") | " .  $row["productName"] . $insulation2." || ".$materials,
            'start'   => $row["deliveryDate"],
            'url'   => 'orderViewSort.php?orderID=' . $row["orderMainID"],
            'color' => $color,
            'materials' => $insulation
        );
echo json_encode($deliveryDateArray);
```

I have tried adding "<'b'>" and "</br" in front of it but if I do that it will just echo the full string out with the  in the event name.

For reference this is how the title is getting applied to the calendar

```
var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    editable:true,
    header:{
      left:'prev,next today',
      center:'title',
      right:'month,agendaWeek',
    },
    editable: true,
    droppable: true, 
    events: 'LoadAllTeams.php'
```

Is there any way I can do this?

*EDIT*
I added the "\n" which brought the page break through, but not sure how to bring the bold through for a specific part of the title string.

```
'title'   => $row["lastName"] . " (" . $row["postcode"] . ") | " .  $row["productName"] . $insulation2." ||\n ".$materials
```

Thanks.

Comment: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/eventRender - then you can customise the content as much as you like

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I added an edit to my OP showing how I got the line break coming through. I am not too sure however how to use eventRender on a specific variable, as I am doing the constructing on the backend PHP side, then with event render the string is already created. Am I just doing it the wrong way putting it all part of the title element?

Comment: Once you're in eventRender, you get access to the whole event including the title. So then you can use JS to break it apart, swap it round, add things to it or whatever else you like, and then overwrite the default content of the event's HTML with your own. The advantage is that at this point you can add HTML rather than just plain text into the title, because you're manipulating a HTML element directly.

Comment: Alternatively you could add an extra "description" property (or whatever else you want to call it, or even multiple properties) to your event object using PHP, and then use eventRender to read those and add them to the final HTML of the event. Doesn't really matter, do whatever's easiest for you.

Comment: Ahh ok perfect thanks. Am I right in understanding then that the events: LoadAllTeams.php is the initial load, then anything in eventRender will overwrite that ? Does it take much longer to render this if I've got alot of events on the calendar?

Comment: `anything in eventRender will overwrite that`...sort of ...it gives you the opportunity to change the visual display of each event. It doesn't change which events get loaded.

Comment: `Does it take much longer to render this if I've got alot of events on the calendar`... depends what you do inside eventRender, and what you define as "a lot". N.b. you're using a fairly old version of fullCalendar, the newer ones are faster all-round. 5.7.0 is the latest at the time of writing.

Comment: Yep perfect, used what you said and it works great. Thanks very much.

Comment: On the second point, what would I need to change in the code to get it to run 5.7.0 ? just change the fullcalendar script reference tag?

Comment: No. Quite a lot has changed. So, depending on what features you've used, you may have to alter a lot of code or only a little bit. Read the upgrade guides: v3 to v4 (this is the biggest change): https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v4/upgrading-from-v3, and then v4 to v5 (far less changes): https://fullcalendar.io/docs/upgrading-from-v4 . P.S. Just looking at the website it appears 5.8.0 has been released, so you may as well target that instead of 5.7.0